# Sent BTC to BCH wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, buy-bitcoins, bitcoin-cash

I have seen this question pop over a few times but I did not find an answer I could understand. This is the scenario:

1. I created a BCH wallet, mistakenly thinking it was a BTC one.
2. I bought BTC and sent to the BCH address
3. Realizing the mistake, I created a BTC wallet using the BCH passphrase.

Is what I did correct? Am I likely to see my bitcoins? Should I do anything else? How can I check where the purchased coins are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is correct: you'll need to use the mnemonic seed phrase that generates the bch wallet, to generate a btc wallet. If you do that, you should see your btc balance.

To see if your btc are at the address you sent them to, just use a block explorer website such as blockchain.info. When you use the mnemonic to generate a btc wallet, it should show you the sae addresses as the bch wallet (as long as the software uses the same derivation scheme. Most software does).

Comment: This did the trick, thank you. For anyone else with the same problem, this is the procedure in case you have a bitcoin.com wallet : https://walletsupport.bitcoin.com/article/110/i-accidentally-sent-btc-to-my-bch-wallet