# How are newly generated key-pairs kept unique to a single cryptocurrency?

Tags: blockchain, wallet

As an extension to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115323/are-all-wallets-always-considered-nodes/115324#115324) and some quick searches on software crypto wallets - my understanding is that any newly generated key-pair is unique to a specific cryptocurrency.

Assuming this is correct, how is this realized? In other words, how is this restriction imposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key pairs are not unique to a specific cryptocurrency but addresses are. You can have the same key pair but it will lead to different addresses in Bitcoin and Litecoin for example, one starting with `bc1` and the other one starting with `L`

Comment: I see, so if a public/private key pair were generated via some wallet app, the public key would then be hashed using an algorithm specific to a cryptocurrency in order to create an address?

Comment: yes pretty much, you would add a prefix to differentiate your coin after hashing

Comment: Thanks vm. And I assume that prefix is somehow pre-set before deployment of the coin or token?

Comment: Doesn't [this sort of question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/64969/13866)  and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/67917/13866) imply that, at some time, BTC, BCH and LTC had compatible and indistinguishable addresses that were not unique to a specific cryptocurrency?